# How do I get a rails page to update when a form is submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, action

I've struggled with this, searched, etc., now I'm ready to ask for help.

I have a controller 'DashboardController', and I have a single view 'dashboard.html.erb'.

The dashboard.html.erb page has three components; some javascript that creates a chart using model data, a div to hold the chart, and a form to select chart options.

This all works.  I can get the form to place the parameters into the query string properly when I submit the form, but the div containing the target for the chart will not update on submit.

Basically looking to have a form driven chart, can't make it happen.  Frustrating.

I'm new at Rails and my knowledge of Controllers, Routing and Actions is still evolving.

Having difficulty with the form_tag aspect of Rails in my code here I've switched to a simple form here.  Still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "orders_chart",
            type: "column"
        },
        title: {
            text: "Sales Billings - <%= params[:sale_year] %>"
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1,2,3,4]
        },
        yAxis: {
            text: "Billings"
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 'Q-' + this.x + ': ' +
                    "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
            }
        },
        series: [{
        name: "Business Unit A",
        data: <%= Sale.where(:year => params[:id], :segment => 'IT    Infrastructure').each.map { |row| row.billings.to_f }.inspect %>
        },{
        name: "Business Unit B",
        data: <%= Sale.where(:year => params[:id], :segment => 'Collaboration').each.map { |row| row.billings.to_f }.inspect %>
        },{
        name: "Business Unit C",
        data: <%= Sale.where(:year => params[:id], :segment => 'MSP').each.map { |row| row.billings.to_f }.inspect %>
        }]
    });


});
```

```
<div id="orders_chart" style="width:560px; height:380px;"></div>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/dashboard" method=""> 
    <select id="sale[:year]" name="sale_year" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">
    <option>Year</option>
    <%  @salesyear = Sale.select(:year).uniq
        @salesyear.each do |years| %>
        <option value="<%=years.year %>"><%=years.year %></option>
    <% end %> 
    </select>

    <select id="sale[:quarter]" name="sale_quarter" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">
    <option>Quarter</option>
    <%  @salesqtr = Sale.select(:quarter).uniq
        @salesqtr.each do |qtr| %>
        <option value="<%=qtr.quarter %>">Q<%=qtr.quarter %></option>
    <% end %> 
    </select>

    <select id="sale[:month]" name="sale_month" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">
    <option>Month</option>
    <%  @salesm = Sale.select(:month).uniq
        @salesm.each do |month| %>
        <option value="<%=month.month %>">Month - <%=month.month %></option>
    <% end %> 
    </select>


<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="false">


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your routes.rb file or your `DashboardsController`, it's difficult to infer what's happening.

I can say that your form tag needs to submit to the correct action with an expected method (likely "post" or "put". You have specified the "/dashboard" action and no method:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/dashboard" method="">
```

I'm guessing "/dashboard" maps to a "get" request in your routes.rb file, like:

```
match "/dashboard", to: "dashboards#dashboard"
```

An atypical, but possibly quick) change, would be to allow both "get" and "post" requests:

```
match "/dashboard", to: "dashboards#dashboard", via: [:get, :post]
```

You would also need to make sure the controller action is set up to handle the params sent by the post request.